# How to use ffmpeg to record audio from a video for first 10 seconds in Python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have RTSP stream coming from a camera which also has audio. My goal is to save the audio. To do this, I have below code:

```
import ffmpeg
ffmpeg.input("rtsp://john:<pwd>@192.168.10.111:5545/Streaming/Channels/291/").output("test.wav", map="0:a:0").run
```

When I terminate the Python script, it saves the test.wav file which has just the audio from the rtsp stream. Now I am trying to save the first 10 sec from the stream into 1 file and then the next 10sec in another file and then it keeps on going until terminated.

To do this, I have thought of putting the ffmpeg stream in a separate thread and to schedule that thread to run every 10 sec. This way a new stream will create which will save the audio for 10sec and will exit, and then this keeps on going. But to achieve this, I need to know how can we just save the initial 10 sec from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved the problem using below code:

```
import os
os.system("ffmpeg -i rtsp://john:<pwd>@192.168.10.111:5545/Streaming/Channels/291/ -q:a 0 -map a -t 10 test.wav")
```

This runs fine and generate a 10sec wav audio file. Next thing to see is how can I keep generating 10sec audio file from rtsp.